# How to find common substrings in more than two strings

Tags: string, string-matching

Given a database of thousands of strings, is there an algorithm to find common substrings between them? I've found examples of algorithms that work with pairs of strings, but I am trying to find an option that doesn't force me to compare every possible pair of strings with said algorithm.

```
/[?&]Using=_layouts/query.iqy.*?&List=[^&]+(script|src|location|document|onlick|onload)/
/[?&](CallbackParam|CallbackFn)=[^&]+?([\x22\x27\x3c\x3e\x28\x29]|eval|script|onload|src)/
/[?&](height|width)=[^&]+?([\x22\x27\x3c\x3e\x28\x29]|script|onload|src)/
```

In these three strings (representing regexes) `src`, `script`, `onload` are examples of shared substrings.

Comment: Your question is vague.  Provide a small sample of the data and what you would like to see as a result.

Comment: Provide expected output. Read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)